# Saving base64String as image on FTP server, saves corrupted file

Tags: ftp, ftp-client

Saving base64String as image on FTP Server is saving it as corrupted file.
I am doing following things

1. converted base64String into byte[].
2. Initialized MemoryStream with byte converted in above step.
3. Opened stream from FTP
4. Write stream on ftp.

Below is the code

```
public bool WriteFromBase64ToFile(string base64, string path, string fileName)
    {
        bool result = false;

        using (FtpClient ftp = new FtpClient())
        {

            // setting ftp properties with required values.
            ftp.ReadTimeout = 999999999;
            ftp.Host = host;
            ftp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
            ftp.Port = Convert.ToInt32(port);
            ftp.DataConnectionType = FtpDataConnectionType.AutoPassive;
            ftp.Connect();
            ftp.ConnectTimeout = 1000000;

            // converting base64String into byte array.
            byte[] file = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);



            if (ftp.IsConnected)
            {
                int BUFFER_SIZE = file.Length; // 64KB buffer
                byte[] buffer = new byte[file.Length];

                // Initializing MemoryStream with byte converted from base64String.
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);

                using (Stream readStream = ms)
                {
                    fileName = fileName.ReplacingSpecialCharacterswithEntities();

                    // Getting stream from ftp and then writing it on FTP server.
                    using (Stream writeStream = ftp.OpenWrite(path + "/" + fileName+".jpg", FtpDataType.Binary))
                    {

                        while (readStream.Position < readStream.Length)
                        {
                            buffer.Initialize();

                            // Reading stream
                            int bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                            // Writing stream
                            writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        }

                        // flushing stream.
                        writeStream.Flush();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        result = true;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: How is it corrupted? Every single byte wrong? Totally different length? Or just a few bytes? Try setting BINARY mode rather than ASCII.

Comment: Already saving as binary in fact  All bytes get saved but when I open file then it shows "Windows Photo Viewer can't open this picture because the file is corrupted, damaged or its too large."

Comment: Does Windows Picture Viewer even understand base64 strings?

Comment: Mark, If you have seen my code I am converting base64String in byte array then converting byte array in stream and then writing stream on FTP. I think this is the process how we save base64String data in binary files whether it is image or other format files.